# Generate system of equations

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function that can generate a system of equations that are solved in a separate program. The equations are generated from a tree of isotope decays, but for simplicity I have the following tree:

[image: decay tree]

So this can be made into the 2 possible decay chains:

```
[(A,0,1,5), (B,1,.4,4), (C,0,.4,0)]

[(A,0,1,5), (B,1,.6,6), (C,0,.6,0)]
```

where the format is (species, number, probability of decay, half-life). I'm trying to make a function that will automatically make a system of equations for a decay tree, which may be more complex than this. The rules are the same though for any tree:

For some species X with parents Y_1, Y_2, ... , Y_n:

`X_final` = sum for each parent species (probability of decay of Y_n -> X * amount of Y_n / half-life of Y_n) - amount of X / half-life of X, which could be represented as:

[image: equation]

and each species in the chain will have its own equation to be solved later on. So for this, I want the following system of equations:

```
A_f = - A_i/5
B1_f = .4 * A_i/5 - B1_i / 4
B2_f = .6 * A_i/5 - Β2_i / 6
C = B1_i / 4 + B2_i / 6
```

Also, if the half-life is `0`, that means it is stable. Currently, I'm generating the system of equation by making a dictionary of strings, but I think there is a better way to do it. I'm planning on turning the strings into variables later on after I make the system with strings. Here is my code:

```
A = 'A'
B = 'B'
C = 'C'
D = 'D'

chain1 = [(A,0,1,5),(B,1,.4,4),(C,0,.4,0),(D,0,.4,0)]
chain2 = [(A,0,1,5),(B,2,.6,6),(C,0,.6,0),(D,0,.6,0)]
master_chain = [chain1, chain2]

def equation_builder(master_chain):
    master_equations = {}
    m = 0
    for chain in master_chain:
        n = 0
        for item in chain:
            if item == chain[0]:
                equation = {str(item[0]) + str(item[1]) + 'f' :\
                '-' +  str(item[0]) + str(item[1])  + 'i/' +  str(item[3])}
                master_equations.update(equation)
            elif str(item[0])+str(item[1])+'f' not in master_equations:
                equation = {str(item[0]) + str(item[1]) + 'f' :\
                str(item[2]/chain[n-1][2])+str(chain[n-1][0]) + 
                str(chain[n-1][1])+'i/' + str(chain[n-1][3])+\
                '-'+str(item[0])+str(item[1])+'i/'+str(item[3])}
                master_equations.update(equation)
            elif str(item[0])+str(item[1])+'f' in master_equations \
            and master_chain[m-1][n-1] != master_chain[m][n-1]:
                old_equation = master_equations[str(item[0])+str(item[1])+'f']
                new_equation = old_equation + '+' +\
                str(item[2]/chain[n-1][2])+str(chain[n-1][0]) +\
                str(chain[n-1][1])+'i/' + str(chain[n-1][3])
                equation = {str(item[0])+str(item[1])+'f' : new_equation}
                master_equations.update(equation)
            n += 1
        m += 1

    return master_equations

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print equation_builder(master_chain)
```

Comment: How does the separate program accept equations to be formatted ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html). SymPy is a symbolic computation toolbox, and very well suited for this use case. You can create a symbol using `A = sympy.Symbol("A")`, and then use `A` in an expression like you'd use any variable. For example, if `A` and `B` are symbols, then if you write `C=A*exp(B)`, `print C` will output `A*exp(B)`. Using an expression's `args` property, you can also access the syntax tree representation of any expression, which might be useful if you want to further process the equations.

Here's an example using your graph (I don't quite understand how you arrived at your results, so this might need some adjustment, but it should suffice to get the idea):

```
import sympy as sp

A, B1, B2, C = sp.symbols("A, B1, B2, C")

chain1 = [(A,0,1,5),(B1,1,.4,4),(C,0,0.4,0)]
chain2 = [(A,0,1,5),(B2,2,.6,6),(C,0,0.6,0)]
master_chain = [chain1, chain2]

finals = {}
for subchain in master_chain:
    for i, (species, number, decay_prob, half_life) in enumerate(subchain):
        input_species = sp.Symbol(str(species) + "_i")
        if species not in finals:
            finals[species] = -input_species / half_life if half_life else 0
        if i < len(subchain) - 1:
            (other_species, other_number, other_decay_prob, other_half_life) = subchain[i+1]
            if other_species not in finals:
                finals[other_species] = -sp.Symbol(str(other_species) + "_i") / other_half_life if other_half_life else 0
            finals[other_species] += input_species * decay_prob / half_life

print finals
```

Output is

```
{C: 0.1*B1_i + 0.1*B2_i, B2: A_i/5 - B2_i/6, A: -A_i/5, B1: A_i/5 - B1_i/4}
```

Note that `Symbol("x") == Symbol("x")`, e.g., symbols are identified by their string representation, so you can safely recreate a symbol every time you need it.

Comment: Would this be easy to modify for arbitrarily large chains, that could include dozens of symbols that I don't know beforehand? My program is automatically calculating and producing the chains, which might be long. This also means I would only know the first symbol when I run the program.

Comment: Sure. I used this approach once to find explicit expressions for  steady-state species in a reaction mechanism with ~150 species and several (automated) quasi steady-state assumptions, so in a setting quite similar to yours. Works like a charm, though if you run sympy's `solve` on your final system to solve for some variables, then that can become a bit slow for very large systems. As long as you only want to generate the expressions, I doubt that there's a *relevant* limit.

Comment: How can I do that without knowing the species beforehand? Like having a function that would automatically create the sympy symbols and return a list of all of them. Such as if I have a list of string variables str_var = ['a','b','c',...'n'] and want a function that automatically creates a sympy symbol for each of these?

Comment: `sym = map(sp.Symbol, str_var)`